# Can't get the ApplyCurrentValues(Entity) to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

Im working on the update section for my application , i want to use  the ApplyCurrentValues but it seems not working(unknown)

`Dim e = (From o In x.Concours Where o.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours Select o).FirstOrDefault()

x.ApplyCurrentValues(e.EntityKey.EntitySetName,concours)
x.savechanges()`

in order to make it work I've changed the code to this :

```
 x.Concours.Attach(New Concour With {.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours})
        Dim e = New Concour With {.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours}
        x.Entry(concours).CurrentValues.SetValues(e)
        x.SaveChanges()
```

but it gives me this error

> Can not call member 'CurrentValues​​' for entity type 'Concour' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context, call the Add method of DbSet or Attach.

so, i've used instead this :

```
 Dim e = (From o In x.Concours Where o.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours Select o).FirstOrDefault()
        x.Concours.Attach(New Concour With {.numero_concours = e.numero_concours})
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)x).ObjectContext.ApplyCurrentValues("Conours", e)

        x.SaveChanges()
```

but it's giving me a syntax error on the ((IobjectContext.....
any suggestions please !!!

---

```
 Public Sub UpdateConcours(concours As Concour) Implements IConcoursRepository.UpdateConcours


      Dim e = (
From o In x.Concours
Where o.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours
Select o)
.First()
x.Entry(e)
.OriginalValues
.SetValues(concours)
       x.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim e = (
    From o In x.Concours
    Where o.numero_concours = concours.numero_concours
    Select o)
    .First()

x.Entry(e)
    .OriginalValues
    .SetValues(concours)

x.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

x.savechanges()
```

Comment: I've trying it but nothing has changed in my data base I can't see what's the problem :(

Comment: what does the object `concours` contain? Is it different to e?

Comment: it is defined as Concour I've put the  update function to have a clear idea

Comment: the code should work. Can you confirm that any of the property values are actually different between `e` and `concours`? Also try adding the call to `DectecChanges()` as in the amended code above.